# How to get PhysicalLocation disk on Windows 2022 like on Windows 2019 via powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, vmware-esxi, windows-server-2019

On Windows Server 2019 i usage `Get-PhysicalDisk | foreach {$_.PhysicalLocation}` its return `SCSI0`. This is exactly what I need. But on Windows Server 2022 its return `PCI Slot 160 : Bus 3 : Device 0 : Function 0 : Adapter 2 : Port 0 : Target 0 : LUN 0`

How can you get the same value of PhysicalLocation on Windows 2022?

Both servers run on VMware virtualization and manage by VMware cloud director

Comment: what do you get when you just run a plain 'Get-PhysicalDisk'? also are the virtual disks on a virtual scsi controller - not all of the virtual controllers are pretending to be SCSI.

Comment: @Chopper3 Get-PhysicalDisk return list of all PhysicalDisk objects, this is the same for both OS.
The controller is used the same Paravirtual (SCSI)